# SQL Server Merge - Pull replication error

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a configuration problem to create a Merge/Pull replication between two databases SQLServer 2012.

The machine Publisher is a Windows Server 2008 R2 not in windows domain, this Server is also the Distributor.
The machine Subscriber is a Windows 8 not in windows domain.

I have made the following settings: in the Published Server i created the distributor's folder, "repldata" and I also shared it  and suser "everyone full control".
The path's folder is \servername\repldata

see image: www.alessandrosenesi.com/download/distributor.jpg

I created Publisher, see image: www.alessandrosenesi.com/download/Publisher.jpg

I created Subscriber see image: www.alessandrosenesi.com/download/subscriber.jpg

I have done some settings in Distributor, Publisher and Subscriber but I don't get  results, I always have access error.

see image: www.alessandrosenesi.com/download/log.jpg

---

```
Error messages:
The schema script 'BOOKING_2.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)

The process could not read file '\\nomemacchina\repldata\unc\nomemacchina$MSSQLSER VER2012_nomereplica\20130930125944\BOOKING_2.sch' due to OS error 5. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)

Access Denied.
(Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL5)
```

---

Can you tell me where is the problem? I have to do this replication but it looks like to be not possible

Thanks in advance
Alessandro

Comment: You need to use a Windows account that has the same username and password on both Publisher and Subscriber and use this account when you create your Subscription "Run under the following Windows account" and have the Connection to the Publisher and Distributor impersonate this account.

Answer (score 0):

Replication across two non-trusted domains or workgroups can be done by using Windows Authentication by configuring **pass-through authentication**.

Create a local Windows account on both the Publisher and Subscriber that has **the same username and password**.  Use this account for the Merge Agent process account and have the connections to the publisher and distributor impersonate the agent process account.  Ensure the account has the permissions required in [Replication Agent Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

This approach is covered in the section ***Use Windows Authentication to Set Up Replication Between Two Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains*** in [HOW TO: Replicate Between Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains or Across the Internet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321822).

If you have anymore questions please let me know.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Brandon 
my problem was just in pass-through autentication, so I'm configuring replication web

Answer (score 0):

This permission issue.need check account full rights on file.